# Solaris Service not showing any status in svcs

Tags: solaris, solaris-10, sun, sparc, ultrasparc

I'm creating a solaris service using SMF by following steps:

1. Create SMF manifest
2. Import manifest via svccfg
3. Enable it using svcadm
4. Check status using svcs

Now in this process i had frequently added/deleted/modified the manifest. Sometimes i killed the service also. But suddenly it stopped showing any status in svcs. No logs are being generated in /var/svc/log/. **How to bring it back working**?

Currently i made it working again by rebooting the machine. Is there any software method also to perform the task?

Solaris 10 sparc architecture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `svcs` is not showing *anything* you've managed to hose SMF.
This tends to happen when you [Kermit Flail](http://gifsoup.com/view/2745106/kermit-yay-flail.html) on systems (`frequently added/deleted/modified the manifest. Sometimes i killed the service also`).

In this situation rebooting is your best option -- SMF is not designed to be "restarted".

Comment: can you please elaborate "hose SMF" and "Kermit Flail" I could not understand these!

Comment: @Bikram990 "You broke it because you made a bunch of changes without properly planning and thinking through the entire process. Next time think everything through very carefully before you start so you're not making multiple changes."

Comment: Now i have little more information on this. i.e. in which scenario its happening. It happens when you start a service and the service crashes/is forcefully killed. In either case shouldn't the SMF restart the service?